# Is there any mobile-friendly way to access filtered feeds?

Tags: support, mobile-web, ios-app, tag-filters

#### Mobile-Web View of Tagsets

I have invested some time to curate some feeds using [tagsets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/improved-tag-sets/) (or [Stack Exchange™ GlobalTag MegaBlender™](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-filters?sort=votes&pageSize=15) or whatever we're calling https://stackexchange.com/filters now).  If I point a desktop browser to https://stackexchange.com/tagsets I get a nice desktop view of my filtered feeds.  Unfortunately, though, if I point my *mobile* browser to the same URL, I get the same desktop-formatted view shown on the left below.  I expected to see a nice mobile-friendly view like the one on the right.

[image] [image]

Surprisingly, even the http://stackexchange.com front page loads in desktop mode:

[image]

#### Custom Filtered Feeds Also Seem to Missing from the App

I have poked and prodded the iOS app and have been unable to find a way to show tagsets there either.  I know there are a handful of ways to filter feeds by question status, tags, etc.  I've been struggling, however, with turning up interesting questions using that method.

#### The Question

**Is there any way, either using the iOS app or the mobile web browser, to get a mobile-friendly view of my curated filtered tagset feeds?**

---

I used Safari, Chrome, and the stackexchange app on an iPhone 5s running iOS 8 to test this.